# Javascript get the dom element a function was called from

Tags: javascript

HTML part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="callme();return false;">foo</a>
```

JS part:

```
function callme() {
  var me = ?; //someway to get the dom element of the a-tag
  $(me).toggle();
}
```

in the JS part can i somehow get the a-tag that this function was called from?

i know i could just pass it as a parameter, but this function is used many many times on a page and i want to avoid putting the parameter everywhere.

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using an onclick attribute (BAD!) you have to pass that into the function.

```
onclick="callme(this); return false;"
```

and the js:

```
function callme(el) {
  var $me = $(el);
  $me.doSomething();
}
```

Another option is to set the context of the function using .call().

```
onclick="callme.call(this,event)"
```

and the js

```
function callme(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: +2 for using `.call()`; -1 for implying that onclick attributes are bad. ;)

Comment: I guess really they aren't BAD, just not a style of programming I would suggest to anyone.

Comment: You assume the OP will use jQuery, he has only tagged this as javascript.

Comment: @Maess It was originally tagged with jQuery, someone edited it. Also, he is using jQuery in his question (or, if you wanted to be exact, he is using either a library or a custom function that uses the same signature as jQuery). `$(me).toggle();` http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10090943/revisions

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple JS function for that

```
 function getEventTarget(event) {
     var targetElement = null;
     try {
         if (typeof event.target != "undefined") {
             targetElement = event.target;
         }
         else {
             targetElement = event.srcElement;
         }
         // just make sure this works as inteneded
         if (targetElement != null && targetElement.nodeType && targetElement.parentNode) {
             while (targetElement.nodeType == 3 && targetElement.parentNode != null) {
                 targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
             }
         }
     } catch (ex) { alert("getEventTarget failed: " + ex); }
     return targetElement;
 };
```

in your html

```
 <a href="#" onclick="callme.call(this,event);return false;">foo</a>
```

in your function

```
 function callme(event) {
   var me = getEventTarget(event); //someway to get the dom element of the a-tag
   $('#'+ me.id).toggle();
 }
```

getEventTarget() will bring back the whole dom object which you can manipulate as you please, or has been said already by other users you can just use

```
 function callme(event) {
      $(this).toggle();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

send `this` parameter to your function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="callme(this);return false;">foo</a>

function callme(me) {
  $(me).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

better dont use onlcick in html markup

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(callme);
})

function callme() {
  var me = this;
  $(me).toggle();
}
```